# How can I get all my Twitter related activity in counts?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

How can I get all my Twitter related activity in counts? Example: my tweet count is 50; my favorite is 10. I need counts of following: mentions, favorites, retweets, liststatus, hometimeline, direct messages, followers, and users I follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the api method `user/show`:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show

It will return all kind of info about a twitter user like:

- favourites_count
- listed_count
- followers_count
- statuses_count
- friends_count

Answer (score 0):

There are a [number of sites](http://pelfusion.com/8-best-twitter-statistics-and-analytics-tools/) that offer Twitter stats.

For what you are after [Twitter Counter](http://twittercounter.com) is probably your best bet for just providing counts (you'll need to give it access to your account for a full profile).